# Determine whether to push or update object in array based on unique ID

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, push

I am trying to write a basic function that will decide whether the object already exists in array of objects based on unique id that is inside this object as a property. Upon searching I came up with this code, and it seems to be doing the job fine, but I can imagine there is a better and faster way to determine whether to push or update the object. If you could share your best answer for this please...

```
var myArray = [
  {
    id: 1,
    car: "Ford"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    car: "Honda"
  }
];

var objToOverwrite = {
  id: 1,
  car: "Bentley" // to overwrite car: "Ford"
};

var objToPush = {
  id: 3,
  car: "Toyota"
};


function pushToArray ( arr, obj ) {


  var existingIds = arr.map((obj) => obj.id);

    if (! existingIds.includes(obj.id)) {
      arr.push(obj);
    } else {
      arr.forEach((element, index) => {
        if (element.id === obj.id) {
          arr[index] = obj;
        };
      });
    };
};

pushToArray ( myArray, objToPush );

console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to cut that down to 1 iteration, you could do something like this:
(note this is an immutable version of your code, so it will return a new array with your result rather than mutating the original array)

```
function pushToArray ( arr, obj ) {
  let updated = false

  let result = arr.map(el => {
    if (obj.id === el.id) {
      updated = true
      return obj
      // or maybe you want to merge objects here? return Object.assign({}, el, obj)
    }

    return el
  })

  if (!updated) {
    result.push(obj)
  }

  return result
}
```

You could also consider using an object keyed by `id` rather than an array. It would simplify the logic:

```
let cars = {
  1: {
    id: 1,
    car: 'Ford',
  },
  2: {
    id: 2,
    car: 'Honda',
  }
}

function updateData ( data, obj ) {
  // again, an immutable version. You can make this mutable by removing the first {}
  return Object.assign({}, data, {
    [obj.id]: obj
  })
}
```

and you can always cast the values to an array when desired:

```
Object.values(cars) // => your original array
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to code it better with good old vanilla JS:

```js
function pushToArray(arr, obj) {
 var value = obj.id;
 var found = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].id === value) {
      arr[i] = obj;
      found = true;
    }     
  };
  if (!found) arr.push(obj);
};

var myArray = [
  {
    id: 1,
    car: "Ford"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    car: "Honda"
  }
];

var objToOverwrite = {
  id: 1,
  car: "Bentley" // to overwrite car: "Ford"
};

var objToPush = {
  id: 3,
  car: "Toyota"
};

pushToArray(myArray, objToOverwrite);

console.log(myArray);
```